# Is grime near the drip pan a problem?

Tags: oil-change, oil-leak, sienna

[image: grime near drip pan- zoomed in]

I’m not sure if I dripped some oil during a previous oil change. Or Is something else happening that I should be worried about?

[image: grime on engine exterior]

The vehicle is a Sienna 2011 V6.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cleaning it as much as possible possible. After cleaning it I suggest you to check your oil levels daily. Check the spot  every day or so if more oil appears there. If more oil appears at the spot and your oil levels go down quickly you have a problem.

Comment: To be clear, the grime isn't a problem in and of itself, but it could mean you're leaking oil.  Also, it's pretty common for older cars to have that amount of grime.  I don't drive new cars, but I might be worried if my 1-3 year old car had a bunch of grime, but (personally speaking) I don't mind that my 18 year old car has more than was in the OP's pictures.